# Take only few values from SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Query which look the price of some replacements (provided by some providers), the thing is that I only need those providers who give me the replacement for the minimun price. (they can be 1, 2 or more)

I have this Query and then I parese it by code, but there is any other way to do what I want only with SQL?

```
select * from tprovider_treplacement where replacement_id = ? order by price asc
```

Thank you so much ☺

Comment: add `limit 2` at the end

Comment: No, this is SQL, and I don't know how many providers give me those replacements, could be 1,2,3,4,16....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
select *
from tprovider_treplacement
where replacement_id = ? and
      price = (select min(price)
               from tprovider_treplacement
               replacement_id = ?
              )
```

This is standard SQL.  Many databases also support this method using window functions:

```
select *
from (select pr.*,
             min(price) over (partition by replacement_id) as minprice
      from tprovider_treplacement pr
      where replacement_id = ?
     ) t
where price = minprice
```

Comment: YES!! That's it!!! Thanks buddy, now that I see It... It wasn't so difficult. Thanks again ^^